# Django Form Preview with model instance

Tags: django, forms

I've followed the official docs for Form Preview in Django, and I've gotten to the point where I can create new records of a particular model.  But what I'm looking to do is update a field in an existing record for a model.  I can't figure out how to pass a model instance, or do I somehow bind a model instance to my model form, with Form Preview?

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 1):

The way you update is given [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) as described in the django documentation.

If you want bind your model instance to a model form you have to look in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#module-django.forms.models) check out the first example given for the article form. If you want to update multiple instances then you will have to use a model formset. Its in the same link further down.

hope that helps.

Comment: Appreciate the try, but I'm trying to determine specifically to use [Form Preview](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-preview/) to update a single model instance.

Comment: Welp the more I think about it, the more I think Form Preview is geared towards creating new records, not modifying existing ones.  So I'm going to give up on this one and use a normal form with a pop-up warning or something.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah seems so. couldn't find out how to give it a existing model instance.